# Uncaught syntax error: unexpected string with json response

Tags: python, json, ajax, django

I'm getting an uncaught syntax error: unexpected string the chrome console when running ajax where I am trying to add a row to the bottom of a html table with the saved data returned with json. I really can't spot it....

```
function create_person() {
    console.log("create person is working!")
    $.ajax({
        url : "{% url 'tande:create_person' %}",
        type: "POST",
        data: { first_name : $('#person-first-name').val(), surname : $('#person-surname').val(), email : $('#person-email').val(), coach_id : $('#person-coach-id').val(), is_coach : $('#person-is-coach').val(), position : $('#person-position').val(), contract_type : $('#person-contract').val()},

        success : function(json) {
            $('#person-first-name').val('');
            $('#person-surname').val('');
            $('#person-email').val('');
            $('#person-coach-id').val('');
            $('#person-is-coach').val('');
            $('#person-position').val('');
            $('#person-contract').val('');
            console.log(json);
            // ERROR OCCURS ON FOLLOWING LINE
            var html = '<tr><td>'+json.personid+'</td><td>'+json.personfirstname+'&nbsp;'+json.personsurname'</td><td>'+json.personposition+'</td><td>'+json.personcontract+'</td><td>'+json.personemail+'</td><td>'+json.personcoachid+'</td></tr>';
            console.log("success"); 
            $('div#talk').html(html);
            console.log(html)
        },

        error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {
            // $('#results').html("<div class='alert-box alert radius' data-alert>Oops! We have encountered an error: "+errmsg+
            //     " <a href='#' class='close'>&times;</a></div>"); // add the error to the dom
            console.log("uh oh"); 
            }
        });
    };
```

The data is saved successfully and the json object is returned to the console, I just can't display it.

```
def create_person(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        print "request post data in view"
        firstname = request.POST.get('first_name')
        print firstname
        lastname = request.POST.get('surname')
        emailadd = request.POST.get('email')
        coachid = request.POST.get('coach_id')
        isacoach = request.POST.get('is_coach')
        positionheld = request.POST.get('position')
        contracttype = request.POST.get('contract_type')

        response_data = {}

        starfruit = Person(first_name=firstname, surname=lastname, email=emailadd, coach_id=coachid, assign_as_coach=isacoach, position=positionheld, contract_type=contracttype)
        starfruit.save()

        response_data['personfirstname'] = starfruit.first_name
        response_data['personsurname'] = starfruit.surname
        response_data['personemail'] = starfruit.email
        response_data['personcoachid'] = starfruit.coach_id
        response_data['personiscoach'] = starfruit.assign_as_coach
        response_data['personposition'] = starfruit.position
        response_data['personcontract'] = starfruit.contract_type
        response_data['personid'] = starfruit.id
        # response_data = {
        # ''
        # }
        print response_data

        return JsonResponse(response_data)

    else:
        print "no post request in view"
        return JsonResponse(response_data)
```

The error I'm getting in the console is just as follows:

(index):845 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

and it refers to the line I've highlighted above

```
var html = '<tr><td>'+json.personid+'</td><td>'+json.personfirstname+'&nbsp;'+json.personsurname'</td><td>'+json.personposition+'</td><td>'+json.personcontract+'</td><td>'+json.personemail+'</td><td>'+json.personcoachid+'</td></tr>';
```

I'm unsure how else to approach this...

Comment: Please give an error text.

Comment: I've made an edit, that's the only error I'm getting in the Chrome developer console

Comment: Your json keys are quite unreadable. Plus, all fields starts by `person`, you could remove this.

Comment: Okay yes point taken I'll rename these so they are more readable. I was trying to avoid having the same variable names for the response data as the field names, I wasn't sure whether this would cause problems so i may have overcomplicated it a little.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing a `+` between `json.personsurname` and the following `'</td><td>'`.

Generally it's a really bad idea to build up HTML like that; this sort of thing is easy to miss.

Comment: Thank you that's fixed it can't believe I missed that.

Is there an alternative I can't think of how else to do this?

Comment: You might try building it up in a for loop. But even splitting it into multiple lines, where each one does `html += ...`, would be clearer.

Comment: Thanks for your help!